# How can I call a C# extension method on an object in StringTemplate?

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

I'm trying to do an if...then in StringTemplate based on the number of items in a collection.  I want to do this:

$if(length(myCollection) > 1)$

But, this is considered logic, and is therefore forbidden (StringTemplate doesn't recognize the > operator).

But, will StringTemplate reflect out an extension method?

My extension method looks like this:

```
public static bool IsMoreThanOne(this ICollection list)
{
    return list.Count > 1;
}
```

If my template looks like this:

```
$if(myCollection.MoreThanOne)$
```

That would find the method if it were a "first order" method (meaning on the "myCollection" object).  But it's not -- it's an extension method, so it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Should your `IsMoreThanOne` method be checking if the `Count` is greater than 1 and not 0? If it is 0, then try `Any` instead of your custom Extension Method.

Comment: Good catch -- edited.  But "Any()" doesn't work either.  If I do myCollection.Any, that won't map to the method because it tries to find "GetAny()" or "IsAny()".

Answer (score 0):

For this *particular* logic you can use the following expression, which basically says "if we skip the first item, does the remaining collection contain any items?":

```
$if(rest(myCollection))$
```

In general, you can create an implementation of `IModelAdaptor` which supports accessing specific properties of your object. If your implementation extends `ObjectModelAdaptor` or `MapModelAdaptor`, you can fall back to `return base.GetProperty(...)` for any properties that you don't handle yourself.